# Turning on ssl_verify_client in Nginx causes Gitlab user identification to fail

Tags: ssh, ssl, ssl-certificate, git, gitlab

We have a private Gitlab instance that we plan on exposing externally, in order to ensure that only employees can connect to the website I have rolled out a small internal CA with user certs in order to have mutual auth. When I turn ssl_verify_client on it does what is expected on the web server side, if no cert (or invalid cert) is presented a 400 error is returned, if a valid cert is submitted then the page loads correctly.

What's weird is that it breaks Gitlab's ability to identify users based on their ssh key.

**Example:**

*Site conf snippet:*

```
ssl_certificate /usr/local/nginx/config/gitlab.chained.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/nginx/config/gitlab.key;
ssl_client_certificate /usr/local/nginx/config/Root_CA.crt;
ssl_ciphers HIGH+aRSA:!kSRP;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_dhparam /usr/local/nginx/config/dh2048.pem;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
#  ssl_verify_client on;
ssl_verify_depth 2;
```

*User box:*

```
% ssh git@gitlab
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Welcome to GitLab, [username]!
Connection to gitlab.domain.local closed.
```

---

*Site conf snippet:*

```
ssl_certificate /usr/local/nginx/config/gitlab.chained.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/nginx/config/gitlab.key;
ssl_client_certificate /usr/local/nginx/config/Root_CA.crt;
ssl_ciphers HIGH+aRSA:!kSRP;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_dhparam /usr/local/nginx/config/dh2048.pem;
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_verify_client on;
ssl_verify_depth 2;
```

*User box:*

```
% ssh git@gitlab
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Welcome to GitLab, Anonymous!
Connection to gitlab.domain.local closed.
```

Can someone explain how this happens and how to fix it? I'm at a loss since they're completely different services surely? Unless there's something I'm missing and the shell handling ssh is making a connection through nginx which is failing. To be honest I don't completely understand how the gitlab architecture works with the integration between ssh, git and gitlab-shell. Maybe if I make this apply to just external connections then it will work? Would appreciate input before I shoot in the dark.

## EDIT:

Okay, that is definately what is happening based on these entries in the *gitlab-shell* logs:

```
E, [2014-02-18T12:12:46.275674 #20681] ERROR -- : API call <GET https://gitlab.premiumsoftware.co.za//api/v3/internal/discover?key_id=2> failed: 400 => <<html>
<head><title>400 No required SSL certificate was sent</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>No required SSL certificate was sent</center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
>.
```

The question is, is it better to give it a client cert to work with or modify the nginx conf so it only requires HTTPS from external IPs? I think the latter is better otherwise there is an SSL connection overhead that is unnecessary since it's only between services on the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a blog post on how I resolved the problem, you can read it [here](http://jonocoetzee.com/gitlab-with-https-and-two-factor-auth/).

As a summary, I setup one nginx server to handle HTTPS connections external to the box (i.e. users browsing the web interface) and a second HTTP server that only listens on the localhost. I then configure gitlab-shell to use connect to `http://localhost/` therefore bypassing the problem of HTTPS certificate errors.

Comment: Linked page does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error after moving our gitlab server to a new domain. The issue was resolved for me after editing 
`/home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml`

The setting changed was the 
`gitlab_url: "https://mynewdomain.com/"`
near the top of the file.